# Can I use "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error message to my advantage in a Matlab program?

Tags: matlab

Can I use "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error message to my advantage in Matlab. Here is what i want to do.
I have a row matrix which "expands" and gets filled during iterations of a for loop that indexes the matrix. Under some specific conditions the matrix may not expand thus creating "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error message. I want to use this i.e the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" event to take some action in my program. Roughly speaking this is what I want to do.

```
If(Index exceeds matrix dimensions)
   Action1;
   Action2;
end
```

Comment: Why do you keep tagging `matlab-guide` in your every question? As stated in its details, *This tag relates to the development of MATLAB applications with a Graphical User Interface  using the interactive GUIDE layout editor.*

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to catch an exception, instead of checking the dimensions with `size`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exceptions:

```
a=[1 2 3];
try
   disp(a(4));  % the risky indexing goes here
catch ex
    if strcmp(ex.identifier,'MATLAB:badsubscript')
        disp('index out of range!'); % bad subscript exception handling goes here
    else
        disp('Some other error occured');
    end
end
```